# Python: how to delete images from folder, which don't have red values (r,g,b)?

Tags: python, opencv

I captured a video of red LEDs, which blinked every 0,5 seconds. I extracted the frames from the video and stored them in a folder. Is there a simple way to delete every frame, which does not show a lightened red LED? (the images are very dark, but not completely black)

EDIT:
[No red LED, dark picture but NOT completely black (not completely [0,0,0] pixel values)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OVfg.jpg)

[Now we catpured the LED, we have red pixel-values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcDsS.jpg)

In my folder, there are many dark frames and many frames with red LED. I want to delete every dark frame

Comment: What did you try? Please, spend some time reading ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You will get better results by following the tips in those articles.

Comment: @accdias I only need all frames, which captured the red LED. Every other frame of the folder is unnecessary for my project. Overall there are 22500 frames in the folder and because it is too much, I want to delete every frame, which did not capture the LED. I need to analyze the Rollung-Shutter-effect of my camera.. that's why I am searching for an easy python code to delete specific the dark frames in the folder

Comment: How about sharing one with and one without so we can see what we are dealing with?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I added 2 examples.. I hope it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could look at the mean Red pixel value on a scale of 0..255 with **ImageMagick** in the Terminal like this:

```
magick QcDsS.jpg -format "%[fx:mean.r*255]"  info:
5.04036
```

Or the brightest red pixel like this:

```
magick QcDsS.jpg -format "%[fx:maxima.r*255]"  info:
255
```

I appreciate your question is tagged `Python` but if your purpose is deleting images and system management type of things, most folk probably do that with `bash` so a command-line tool is probably easier.

Comment: Be aware that bright white LEDs will also have a high red component, so this may not be appropriate if you have other, undisclosed content in your images.